# Decompress multiple .gz to another directory

Tags: gzip

I have multiples files in one directory:

```
/dir1/A.txt.gz
/dir1/B.txt.gz
```

I want to decompress the files so that the originals remain and the decompressed files are in another directory:

```
/dir1/A.txt.gz
/dir1/B.txt.gz
/dir2/A.txt
/dir2/B.txt
```

The command I used didn't have preserve the original .gz files and put them in the same directory:

```
gzip -d /dir1/*.gz
```

How can a decompress each files individually to another directory?

Comment: `cd /dir2/ && for z in /dir1/*.gz; do gunzip $z; done`

Comment: Use `-k` to keep the gzipped files.

Answer (score 2):

```
cp /dir1/*.gz /dir2
gunzip /dir2/*.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
for i in ./*.gz; do gunzip -k $i; y=${i%.gz}; mv $y ./targ; done
```

Where `targ` is where you want the files to go.